# Regridding data from 2D grid to another

Tags: scipy, netcdf

i'm working on a project involving netcdf data analisys. To correctly process the data i need to regrid it to a coarser level. The matrix is in fact multidimensional, but i only need spatial regridding, so basically i have to work with a lat/lon matrix.

The process i had in mind would consist, giving a source 2d grid (the one retrived from the netcdf) and a destination grid ( the one that i need for my calculations) the second of wich is coarser(have less points),in calculating a sort of weight matrix that contains the coefficients needed to compute each point of destination grid.

This will be helpful because i have a bunch of variables laying on the same grid, so if i calculate a weight matrix, the problem is reduced in a sequence of matrices multiplications.

basically what i need is a function f(lat_source,lon_source,lat_dest, lot_dest) that given the coords of the source/destinaiton grids return a matrix of weights that maps the dest lat/lon onto the source one.

is there something already implemented ? Or some reads that could point me in the right direction ?

I know there are different interpolation methods that could be used, but, for the sake of the argument, let's suppose a linear interpolation.

Comment: Read http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html#multivariate-interpolation and the "data on a grid" part.

Comment: @pv. none of this functions seems to return a weight matrix, looks like they only perform interpolation... or am i missing something ?

Comment: If you can use another language for this, I recommend NCL http://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Applications/regrid.shtml